# Integral : $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(ax)}{x^2} dx. (a>0) $

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals, complex-integration

I have to calculate $\displaystyle\int_0^{\infty} \dfrac{1-\cos(ax)}{x^2} dx. (a>0) $

My attempt:

Let $f(z):= \dfrac{1-e^{iaz}}{z^2}.$

$C_1 : z=t, t:0 \to R$

$C_R : z=Re^{i\theta}, \theta : 0 \to 2\pi $

$C_2 : z=te^{2\pi i}, t:R \to 0$

$C_r : z=re^{i\theta}, \theta : 2\pi \to 0$

$(R>r)$

$f(z)$ is a regular analytic function, so I can use Cauchy's Integral Theorem.

$\displaystyle\int_{C_1} f(z)dz
+\displaystyle\int_{C_R} f(z)dz
+\displaystyle\int_{C_2} f(z)dz
+\displaystyle\int_{C_r} f(z)dz
=0.
$

But this didn't work because $\lim_{r\to 0} \displaystyle\int_{C_r} f(z)dz \neq 0$.

How should I set $f(z)$ and Integral route?

Comment: did you try differentiating under the integral sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that
$$
I(a) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{1 - \cos (ax)}}{x^2}dx}  = a\int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{1 - \cos t}}{t^2}dt}  = aI(1).
$$
Now
$$
I(1) = I'(a) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\sin (ax)}}{x}dx}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{\sin t}}{t}dt}  = \frac{\pi }{2}.
$$
Hence, $I(a)=\frac{\pi }{2} a$.